# How to use 2 Strings in ACTION_CALL in android studio

Tags: java, android

I wrote this code to call a number with my app, but I should use two strings to join these two numbers and call.

Actually the number is like this ( *123*phone number* The number in EditText # ) I should use 2 strings to have a code like this ( *123*phone number* String2 + String1 )

Strin1 = #, but with this code the button doesn't work.

How to call with 2 strings?

The Java code is as below:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);

    this.btnCall = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_call));
    this.money = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextsend));

    btnCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_CALL);
            String str2 = money.getText().toString();
            Object object;
            try {
                String str1 = URLEncoder.encode("#", "UTF-8");
                object = str1;
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException localUnsupportedEncodingException) {
                for (;;) {
                    localUnsupportedEncodingException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            i.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "*123*0794100163*" + str2 + object));

            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(About.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: try to log your full string before you parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you gyes for your great answers, and sorry for replays.
Finaly I found my answer which it will call from phone.
The code is shown below:

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MonySendActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

```
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MonySendActivity.this, new String[] { "android.permission.CALL_PHONE" }, 1);

        String str2 = roshanmoney.getText().toString();
        String str3 = roshannumber.getText().toString();
        String objectmoney;
        try {
            String str1 = URLEncoder.encode("#", "UTF-8");
            objectmoney = str1;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException localUnsupportedEncodingException) {
            for (;;) {
                localUnsupportedEncodingException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:*123*07" + str3 + "*" + str2 + objectmoney));
        startActivity(i);
        return ;
    }else {
        String str2 = roshanmoney.getText().toString();
        String str3 = roshannumber.getText().toString();
        String object;
        try {
            String str1 = URLEncoder.encode("#", "UTF-8");
            object = str1;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException localUnsupportedEncodingException) {
            for (;;) {
                localUnsupportedEncodingException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:*123*07"+ str3 + "*" + str2 + object));
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a call with "#" or "*" in your phone number String.
Use Intent.ACTION_DIAL instead

```
String dialString = "*100*9819283913*123123#";
Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse ("tel:" + Uri.encode (dialString)));
startActivity (i);
```

No need to check for permission of android.permission.CALL_PHONE in manifest file

**Output:**
[image]